# Grok - how to add field with values from existing fields?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Use case:

The following is a pull of metrics from a jmx application.

```
metric_value_number:1 
path:/opt/jmxd/ 
@timestamp:January 5th 2018, 12:16:16.652 
@version:1 
host:server1 
metric_path:dumper.PlugableGroupConsumer-0.running_bool 
type:jmx 
_id:NLEJxmABgpl3QdqYJlaX 
_type:jmx 
_index:jmx-2018.01.05 
_score: -
```

The question is how to build a grok pattern, which will use the `metric_path:` as field name(it's changing constantly) and use `metric_value_number` as the numeric value?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to create a field named "dumper.PlugableGroupConsumer-0.running_bool" with a value of 1?

If so, you can use mutate's [add_field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-add_field).